# MySQL Order By Date And Boolean Priority: Number To Date Weirdness

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I have a table which I want to get sorted by date_created descending, but there is also a pinned column which if that is 1 the row should be at the top regardless of date. The query I've come up with, which does work, is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
  WHERE id = SOMEID
  ORDER BY (CASE WHEN pinned = 1 THEN 3 ELSE date_created END) DESC;
```

What I'm wondering is why mysql thinks that the number 3 is greater than all of these dates from the year 2020. My current theory is that mysql is converting 3 to the date January 1st 3000 since if I use the value 2 then the pinned rows are not in the correct place.

My questions then are: How is 3 greater than 2020-06-22 08:59:09 and is there a better way of forming this query?

Extra question: Is there a way that I can ensure that the pinned rows are also sorted by date_created descending with respect to all other pinned rows? This is less important to being the best answer than the previous two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you're right, but for the opposite reason. It's just a simple string comparison:

```
SELECT '2020-01-01' > '3';
+--------------------+
| '2020-01-01' > '3' |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

SELECT '2020-01-01' < '3';
+--------------------+
| '2020-01-01' < '3' |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As an alternative, consider `ORDER BY pinned = 1 DESC, date`

Comment: Thanks, that's a clean solution and your explanation makes sense.